# How to print specific value from a list?

Tags: python

I'm fresh at python and i don't know how to do that, If I have a list with loop, for example

```
cars = ["Ford", "Volvo", "BMW"]

for x in cars:
  print(x)
```

How can I print the second index, I did this but it doesn't work

```
cars = ["Ford", "Volvo", "BMW"]

for x in cars:
  print(x[1])
```

Comment: Why are you looping in your second piece of code? All you need is `print(cars[1])` That loop doesn't make sense

Comment: From where are you learning python?

Answer (score 0):

If the index is known, just print(x[index]) should work fine. The reason why it isn't currently working is that you have added a redundant loop in your second piece of code. In this code,  x would hold the value of the item being iterated upon in the list i.e. x is a string. So you don't need to access any index on x. print(x) should be sufficient in case you want to keep the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the for loop you would be using it to print each element of the list, a for loop makes no sense if you know the position you want to print, you can print the value of position 2 with just the print function

cars = ["Ford", "Volvo", "BMW"]

print(cars[1])

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit of a misunderstanding of how the `for` loop works, so I'll try to explain what it does first.

`for x in cars:` loops over each element in `cars`, and names the said element as `x`. This means that:

```py
for x in cars:
  print(x)
```

is essentially the same as

```py
x = cars[0]
print(x) // prints Ford
x = cars[1]
print(x) // prints Volvo
x = cars[2]
print(x) // prints BMW
```

The problem with your answer lies in that when you try to print `x[1]`, x is not an array - it's a string. So you're trying to print the 1st index of each element in the list, which would output "o", "o", and "M" (F**o**rd, V**o**lvo, B**M**W).

---

To answer your question on how to print a specific value from a list, you don't need a loop. You can just directly access the list as followed:

```py
print(cars[1])
```

This will print `Volvo`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i, j in enumerate(cars):
    if i == 1:
        print(j)
```

This code prints Volvo

Comment: Hello, R. Goldberg